# Need WOPI integration to support 2FA scenarios

Tags: officedev

For the WOPI protocol to be used for integration with mobile and Web Office clients in secure corporate environments it needs to support two-factor authentication.

Comment: What is your question? We're just ordinary people who answer programming questions. If you have a feature request, you really need to talk to Microsoft